# Excel Formula Query - How to auto copy data to specific sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, spreadsheet

Microsoft Excel question:

How can I auto copy certain data from a main/master sheet to other specified sheets?

E.G - Master sheet logs all the data.  I would like each row of data to be copied to the corresponding sheet.  The data either goes to sheet red/blue/green depending on what is entered in the cells for column D.

Edit: image attached below to try and illustrate what I'm saying better.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following macro splits the main sheet into groups. The number of columns and rows is insignificant. Only last column matters as the macro relies on mapping between sheet name and Code name. If the sheet with a given code value does not exist the record will be remained untouched in the main sheet. As a must have the code name must be in the last column.

```
Option Explicit
'Assumptions:
'The Code is in the last column
Sub DataSplitter()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next
Dim noOfRows As Long
Dim noOfColumns As Long
Dim noOfRowsInCodeSheet As Variant
Dim i As Long 'counter
Dim j As Long 'counter
Dim sE As Boolean 'sheet exists flag
Dim sheetEmpy As Boolean
Dim code As String
Dim c As New Collection 'store noOfRowsInCodeSheet
Dim cRows As New Collection 'rows to delete

j = 1
'check how many columns
Do While Len(Cells(1, j).Value) > 0
j = j + 1
Loop
noOfColumns = j - 1

'check how many rows
i = 1
Do While Len(Cells(i, 1).Value) > 0
    i = i + 1
Loop
noOfRows = i - 1

'loop through the data
For i = 2 To noOfRows
    code = Cells(i, noOfColumns).Value
    'check if sheet exists
    If Sheets(code) Is Nothing Then
        sE = False ' sheet with code name does not exist
    Else
        sE = True ' sheet with code name exists
    End If
    'if sheet exists then check the noOfRows based on code
    If sE = True Then
        noOfRowsInCodeSheet = c.Item(code)
        If noOfRowsInCodeSheet Is Empty Then
            'the sheet was not visited during this execution
            'check no of rows in code sheet
            j = 1
            Do While Len(Sheets(code).Cells(j, 1).Value) > 0
                j = j + 1
            Loop
            noOfRowsInCodeSheet = j - 1
            If noOfRowsInCodeSheet = 0 Then
                'add headers
                For j = 0 To noOfColumns
                    Sheets(code).Cells(1, j).Value = Cells(1, j).Value
                Next j
                noOfRowsInCodeSheet = noOfRowsInCodeSheet + 1
            End If
            If noOfRowsInCodeSheet >= 1 Then
                noOfRowsInCodeSheet = noOfRowsInCodeSheet + 1
                'populate rows
                For j = 1 To noOfColumns
                    'Sheets(code).Cells(noOfRowsInCodeSheet, j).Value = Cells(i, j).Value 'it works but looses formatting
                    Cells(i, j).Copy
                    Sheets(code).Cells(noOfRowsInCodeSheet, j).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
                    Sheets(code).Cells(noOfRowsInCodeSheet, j).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Next j
                c.Remove code
                c.Add Item:=noOfRowsInCodeSheet, Key:=code
                cRows.Add Item:=i, Key:=CStr(i)
            End If
        End If
    Else
        'if sheet does not exist then do nothing (it's possible to _
        'automatically add it if required)
    End If
Next i

‘Uncomment to MOVE (cut-paste) rows (3 below lines)
‘Comment to COPY (copy-paste) rows (3 below lines)
For j = cRows.Count To 1 Step -1
    Rows(cRows.Item(j)).EntireRow.Delete
Next j

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Pretty much exactly what I was looking for. But would like the data to remain on the main sheet and just copy it to the others

Comment: It's possible with the given code. I've edited the comment at the bottom so that it is hopefully more meaninful now. If you comment the last loop which starts with this line For j = cRows.Count To 1 Step -1 then the data will remain untouched on the main sheet.